# Code splitting with React Loadable and routes with containers

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom, react-loadable

I want to achieve code splitting of every main route so every page will have its own file (along with its subcomponents), for example I have a main render function with `Route` components that points to containers:

```
    <Route path={`path1`} component={foo.container} />
    <Route path={`path2`} component={bar.container} />
```

Each container looks something like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
... actions etc ...
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
... selectors etc ...
})

const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);

export default compose(withConnect)(MyComponent);
```

I tried to wrap a container and reference that in the route but it didn't work:

```
export default Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./MyContainer'),
  loading() {
    return (<div>Loading...</div>)
  },
});
```

So what am supposed to wrap then?

Comment: check your .babelrc file and see if you are using plugin syntax-dynamic-import. As your dynamic import in react-loadable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified example how to achieve code splitting with `react-router` and `react-loadable`:

**MyPage.jsx** - *the page what you want to generate in a separate file*

```
import React from 'react';

const MyPage = () => (
    <div>My page</div>
);

export default MyPage;
```

**LoadableMyPage.jsx** - *wrapper to make your page loadable*

```
import React from 'react';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

const LoadableMyPage = Loadable({
    loader: () => import('./MyPage'),
    loading: () => <div>Loading...</div>,
});

const LoadableMyPage = () => (
    <LoadableMyPage />
);

export default LoadableMyPage;
```

**Router.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import LoadableMyPage from './LoadableMyPage';

const Router = () => (
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={LoadableMyPage} />
        ...
    </Switch>
);
```

As @Mohit Tilwani mentioned, the dynamic import plugin is required because it's currently in `stage-3` and not part yet of the ECMAScript.

> https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import

I started working on my own React boilerplate where I implemented the same code splitting. Do not hesitate to check it if you got stucked.

> https://github.com/peetya/react-boilerplate

Comment: I have containers for each of the routes, the containers do the connect with the store with all the relevant selectors and reducers. How do you use them with this?

Comment: Also you have `const LoadableMyPage` twice, I assume the second one should have a different name.

Comment: How do you check if it does anything?